# How do I remove the item with the highest value in an unsorted array?

Tags: java

So right now I am trying to code a function that will remove the highest value in an unsorted array.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
    @Override
public void remove() throws QueueUnderflowException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new QueueUnderflowException();
    } else {
        int priority = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < tailIndex; i++) {
            while (i > 0 && ((PriorityItem<T>) storage[i - 1]).getPriority() < priority)
            storage[i] = storage[i + 1];
            i = i - 1;
        }
        /*int max = array.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array.get(i) > max) {
        max = array.get(i);
        }*/
    }
        tailIndex = tailIndex - 1;
    }
```

Here I have my attempt at this:

```
int priority = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < tailIndex; i++) {
        while (i > 0 && ((PriorityItem<T>) storage[i - 1]).getPriority() < priority)
        storage[i] = storage[i + 1];
        i = i - 1;
```

The program runs no bother but still deletes the first item in the array instead of the highest number. This code was given my my college lecturer for a different solution but unfortunately it doesn't work here.

Would this solution work with enough altercations? Or is there another solution I should try?

Thanks.

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet in the question can be updated to below code, while keeping the same data structure i.e. queue and this updated code has 3 steps - finding the index of largest element, shifting the elements to overwrite the largest element and finally set the tailIndex to one less i.e. decrease the size of the queue.

```
    @Override
public void remove() throws QueueUnderflowException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new QueueUnderflowException();
    } else {
        int priority = 0;
        int largeIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tailIndex; i++) {
          if (((PriorityItem<T>) storage[i]).getPriority() > priority) {
            priority = ((PriorityItem<T>) storage[i]).getPriority();
            largeIndex = i ;
          }
        }

        for(int i = largeIndex; i < (tailIndex - 1) ; i++)
          storage[i] = storage[i + 1];
    }
    tailIndex = tailIndex - 1;
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
Find the highest index.

```java
int[] array;
int highIndex = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < highIndex.size(); i++)
    if (array[highIndex] < array[highIndex])
        highIndex = i;
```

**Step 2**
Create new array with `new int[array.size() - 1]`

**Step 3**
Move all values of array into new array (except the highest one).

My hint: When its possible, then use a `List`. It reduces your complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `largest Number` and it's `index` then copy each number to its preceding number. After that, you have two options:

- Either add `Length - 1` each time you iterate the array.
- Or copy the previous array and don't include removed number in it.

Working Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class stackLargest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] unsortedArray = {1,54,21,63,85,0,14,78,65,21,47,96,54,52};
        int largestNumber = unsortedArray[0];
        int removeIndex = 0;
        // getting the largest number and its index
        for(int i =0; i<unsortedArray.length;i++)
        {
            if(unsortedArray[i] > largestNumber)
            {
                largestNumber = unsortedArray[i];
                removeIndex = i;
            }
        }

        //removing the largest number
        for(int i = removeIndex; i < unsortedArray.length -1; i++)
            unsortedArray[i] = unsortedArray[i + 1];

        // now you have two options either you can iterate one less than the array's size
        // as we have deleted one element
        // or you can copy the array to a new array and dont have to add " length - 1" when iterating through the array
        // I am doing both at once, what you lke you can do
        int[] removedArray = new int[unsortedArray.length-1];
        for(int i =0; i<unsortedArray.length-1;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf(unsortedArray[i] + " ");
            removedArray[i] = unsortedArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Use `List` whenever possible, it will not only reduce complexity, but, comes with a very rich methods that will help you a big deal.